# Elasticsearch 5.x has no mechanism to silently drop fields that don't conform to particular type based (given mapping)?

Tags: elasticsearch, types, schema

Elasticsearch docs ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html) state the following:

> By default, when a previously unseen field is found in a document,
>   Elasticsearch will add the new field to the type mapping.

So, if we create a document (for which no index/type mappings exist before hand) like this:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/food/1' -d \
'{
  "name": "pie",
  "delicious": true,
  "age": 100.5
}'
```

the types are discovered automatically and the mappings  for the type `food` in index `my_index` become:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "food": {
        "properties": {
          "age": { "type": "float" },
          "delicious": { "type": "boolean" },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I attempt to add a new document to index/type  my_index/food for which one of the field values
violates the 'contract' of the mapping specification then I find elasticsearch returns an
error and declines to index the offending document.

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/food/2' -d \
'{
  "name": "goat",
  "delicious": false,
  "age": true
}'
```

leads to:

```
 mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [age]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [age]","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Current token (VALUE_TRUE) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors\n
```

My question is: is there any way to configure elastic search so that my attempt to 
index this document: `{ "name": "goat", "delicious": false, "age": true }`

would just drop the (improperly typed) field 'age', and index the rest of the given document as follows:

```
'{ "name": "goat", "delicious": false}'
```

I'm guessing no search feature is available, but wanted to check. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty new to ElasticSearch and doubly so for the +5.x branch, but I just stumbled on the `ignore_malformed` mapping parameter after reading your question.

> Sometimes you don’t have much control over the data that you receive. One user may send a login field that is a date, and another sends a login field that is an email address.
>
> **Trying to index the wrong datatype into a field throws an exception by default, and rejects the whole document. The ignore_malformed parameter, if set to true, allows the exception to be ignored. The malformed field is not indexed, but other fields in the document are processed normally.**

This last detail seems to describe your use case, not sure, been huffing too much solder fumes this week. :)

Here's the docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html

Comment: looks perfect for what I need.    The solder fumes are clearly helping ;^)  I should try that if i run out of glue.  thnx !